# If exists error in nested query

Tags: postgresql

I am learning sql and I am doing another tricky query. I have the following tables.

players: Columns: name, school_name, gender

simple: Columns: player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, category, tournament_number, score

doubles: Columns: player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, category, tournament_number, score

My entries in the simple and double tables will be similar to this. Each line is the score by a player at a specific tournament number.

```
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 1, 40
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 2, 30
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 3, 60
Anne, MIT, Senior, 1, 45
Anne, MIT, Senior, 2, 55
Anne, MIT, Senior, 3, 20 etc.
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t1.player_name_fkey,
       t1.school_name_fkey,
       score_simple,
       score_double,
       (t2.score_simple + t1.score_double) AS sum_scores
FROM (
  SELECT player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey,
         sum(score) AS score_double
  FROM double
    LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = double.player_name_fkey
  WHERE category = 'Cadet'
    AND gender = 'Féminin'
  GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
           school_name_fkey
) t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT player_name_fkey,
           school_name_fkey,
           sum(score) AS score_simple
    FROM simple
      LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = simple.player_name_fkey
    WHERE category = 'Cadet'
      AND gender = 'Féminin'
    GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
             school_name_fkey
  ) t2
         ON t1.player_name_fkey = t2.player_name_fkey
        AND t1.school_name_fkey = t2.school_name_fkey
ORDER BY sum_scores DESC
```

The problem that arises is when one of the tables do not have a matching score for a person, it returns an empty string for that score. I wish that in this case, the score gets set to zero. So I tried this:

```
SELECT t1.player_name_fkey,
       t1.school_name_fkey,
       score_simple,
       score_double,
       (t2.score_simple + t1.score_double) AS sum_scores
FROM (IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey,
         sum(score) AS score_double
  FROM double
    LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = double.player_name_fkey
  WHERE category = 'Cadet'
    AND gender = 'Féminin'
  GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
           school_name_fkey) t1
) score_double = 0
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT player_name_fkey,
           school_name_fkey,
           sum(score) AS score_simple
    FROM simple
      LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = simple.player_name_fkey
    WHERE category = 'Cadet'
      AND gender = 'Féminin'
    GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
             school_name_fkey
  ) t2
         ON t1.player_name_fkey = t2.player_name_fkey
        AND t1.school_name_fkey = t2.school_name_fkey
ORDER BY sum_scores DESC
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

> "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT".

Comment: Are you maybe just looking for `coalesce()`? e.g. `coalesce(score_simple,0)`?

Comment: Perhaps `FULL JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Bingo, coalesce is exactly what I was looking for. Please submit that answer so I can accept it. Thank you again!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thank you for the comment! Unfortunately, the FULL JOIN does not return what I am expecting (couple of empty lines and the score still remains empty as opposed to 0.